# My Curves Adjustment's Gray Point Eyedropper Doesn't Seem to be working Properly

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photo-editing

I am trying to use my curves adjustment to white balance, it use to work but now it doesn't. Every time I use my gray point eye dropper on a gray area, it turns my image yellow. I even tested it out on a gray card and the same thing happens. It didn't always do this, I must have accidentally changed some setting. Does anyone know what can be causing this? ( I know I can use camera raw or Lightroom to white balance but I would like to figure this out so I have the option to use curves if I'd like.)

Thank you!

Comment: If you add a screenshot of your problem, it will be easier to be of assistance :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you double-click the gray point eye dropper, a color picker called "Color Picker (Target Midtone Color)" appears.

You might have chosen a yellowish grey. The color should be neutral grey: RGB(128, 128, 128).